# Loading a PHP file and set variable based on selection

Tags: php, jquery

I need to load the content of a PHP file using jquery based on what is selected by the user in one or more select fields.

I can use...

```
$("#first-choice").change(function() {
    $("#second-choice").load("getter.php?choice=" + $("#first-choice").val() );
});
```

...to create the variable 'choice' and when the 'first-choice' field is set by the user.

However, what if I want to use 2 variables based on two drop down selectors, to set the variable 'choice' (based on the selection of #first-choice)  and choice2 (based on the selection of #second-choice).

So I would want to load a PHP file something like  getter.php?choice=first-choice&choice2=second-choice

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: If user selects (in sequence), `first-choice` and then `second-choice` and another user selects `second-choice` first and then `first-choice` then how will you decide when to load page ??? You need some other user interaction to load page.

Comment: OK, so this is what I am trying to do...

I am working with an API that has several XML feeds.   The first feed gives the country, the second feed gives the city, and the third feed gives a location within the city.

The country feed will make up the first drop down selector.  That's the easy bit.  But when the user selects the country I need to load a second selector with all the cities for that country, so I need to call the API to get all the cities, then when the city is selected I need to call another XML feed that returns the locations for that city and display them in a third selector.

Answer (score 0):

here's how i would handle this situation..

don't treat your selects as ids.  use a single class for all select options, then bind .change() to all selects using a class-based selector. if you do this, you can iterate over X number of selects, use their ids as the query argument variable and their values as each query value.  I created a quick demo for you on jsfiddle.  I also posted the code for you below....

[Here is my demo on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nickadeemus2002/WVPxQ/)

```
    <div>
    <select class="php-options" id='first-choice' name='first-choice'>
         <option value='1-0'>choose</option>
        <option value='1-1'>1-1</option>
       <option value='1-2'>1-2</option>
        <option value='1-3'>1-3</option>
        <option value='1-4'>1-4</option>
      <option value='1-5'>1-5</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <select class="php-options" id='second-choice' name='second-choice'>
        <option value='2-0'>choose</option>
        <option value='2-1'>2-1</option>
       <option value='2-2'>2-2</option>
        <option value='2-3'>2-3</option>
        <option value='2-4'>2-4</option>
      <option value='2-5'>2-5</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="request-url"></div>





$(document).ready(function(){
//treat your select options with classes,
//bind change event on each select
$('.php-options').change(function(e){
    var urlValues = [],
        parameterArgs = "";
    //loop selects to build parameters
    $('.php-options').each(function(i,v){
        var optValue = $(this).val(),
            optId=$(this).attr('id'),
            parameter = ""+optId+"="+optValue;
        urlValues.push(parameter);
    });
    //build parameter string
     parameterArgs =urlValues.join("&");

    //output query
    $('#request-url').text('getter.php?'+parameterArgs);        
});
```

});